# Installed Qemu 4.0 but version 2.11 still shows in terminal

Tags: apt, compiling, qemu

I installed qemu using apt and got version 2.11.
Decided to use a more recent version and downloaded the source for 4.0.
Removed apt version with a:

```
apt remove qemu
```

successfully compiled version 4.0, but running "--version" results in version 2.11:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.11.1(Debian 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.13)
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

have I removed it wrongly? will I have to compile it again? It took so much time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm new to compiling programs, I didn't know I had to `make install` after `make` to put the binaries in /bin.

After running it, I got the 4.0.0 version in my $PATH

Answer (score 0):

Qemu packaging is split up into many pieces for better dependency management.
The system emulation binaries are in qemu-system-x86.
So if you want to get rid of that binary this is the package to remove.

You can always check which package a binary belongs to with dpkg:

```
$ dpkg -S qemu-system-x86_64
qemu-kvm: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64-spice
qemu-system-x86: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
```

Comment: ah excuse me, I don't want to just get hid of Qemu I want my shell to execute version 4.0.0 that a I recently installed